# Why does return address(player) return a weird string?

Tags: solidity, addresses, string, frontend, returndata

I am trying to get the player's address through front end and when I run through the solidity function that should return the player's address, it would return `41fdc7dcc7846a7fb2b09712221ebf2fb38ca3056c` instead. Is there something I need to do in solidity before I can return it? Thanks!

Comment: You should post a short code snippet so we can easily reproduce the result. It is possibly a contract issue or the client-side process that calls it. This string looks truncated or otherwise distorted (it doesn't map to either an address or a transaction). How does what you get differ from your expectation?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/0NB9mhDH, im trying to get the ethereum/tron wallet address to display on the site

Comment: That much looks okay.